# Need to resume Interval on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, intervals

I'm running into a brick wall and don't seem to be able to solve this.
Basically, I am setting an Interval (abcd) because I want to execute a snippet of code each time a popup div becomes visible on the page.

```
function confirmationVisibility() {  
        if ($("#box2").is(":visible")) {
    //If confirmation box is visible 
          console.log('cool beans');
          clearInterval(abcd); //stop timer
          abcd = null;
        }     
}
var abcd;
abcd = setInterval(confirmationVisibility, 100);
```

This works just fine for one time, but I am struggling with finding a way to have the interval resume for the next time that popup gets triggered.

Do you have any idea how I could accomplish this? I've tried restarting the interval when the user clicks the "close popup" button but it does not seem to work that way.

Thanks a lot,
Alexis.

Comment: "I want to execute a snippet of code each time a popup div becomes visible on the page." -- Can you be a bit more clear here?  What is causing this popup to show up?  Why don't you use that triggering mechanism to execute your code?  Using `setInterval` in this case may be a poor substitute for keeping track of the popup's state.

Comment: Calling `setInterval` should restart/resume the timer. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u572a0jq/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call "clearInterval" it ends the repetitions started by "setInterval"

How about this:

```
function confirmationVisibility() {  
    if ($("#box2").is(":visible")) {
//If confirmation box is visible 
      console.log('cool beans');
      clearInterval(abcd); //stop timer
      abcd = null;
    } 
    else{
      abcd = setInterval(confirmVisibility, 100); 
    }           
}
var abcd;
abcd = setInterval(confirmationVisibility, 100);
```

Comment: Yup, I understand that and am looking for a workaround. I need my code to fire only ONCE each time the popup becomes visible. When it becomes hidden again, the timer could restart, right?

Answer (score 0):

Set the Interval again when the Popup is visible.

See this link http://jsfiddle.net/9La0L6f7/3/ or codes below.

I set another Interval to simulate the hiding of the popup.

```
var abcd;

function confirmationVisibility() {  
        if ($("#box2").is(":visible")) {

          alert('cool beans');
          clearInterval(abcd); //stop timer;
        }     
}

abcd = setInterval(confirmationVisibility, 100);

/* closing of popup simulation here */ 
setInterval(function(){
    $("#box2").css("visibility", "hidden");
}, 5000);

/* solution here, declare abcd again */
$("#showbox2").click(function(){
    $("#box2").css("visibility", "visible");
    abcd = setInterval(confirmationVisibility, 100);
});
```